# Grails: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: grails

I use Grails 2.3.11 and Hibernate with MySQL.

I get this strange error:

```
Message
Executing action [handle] of controller [org.grails.jaxrs.JaxrsController] in plugin [jaxrs] caused exception: Runtime error executing action
Caused by
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Trace

```
 Line | Method
->>  159 | invoke                                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    354 | handleAction                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|    231 | executeAction . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    197 | handleURI                             in     ''
|    121 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     72 | handleRequest                         in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
|     48 | handle . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
|    355 | doDispatch                            in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
|    851 | doService . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    953 | processRequest                        in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    855 | doPost . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    646 | service                               in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    829 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    727 | service                               in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    303 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|     52 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    198 | doFilter                              in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    343 | invokeDelegate                        in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    260 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    100 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    100 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    100 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    100 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    748 | invoke                                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
|    486 | processRequest . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    411 | doForward                             in     ''
|    338 | forward . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    332 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
|    297 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo . . . in     ''
|    288 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo       in     ''
|    217 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
|    106 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    233 | executeFilterChainWithWrappedResponse in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
|    208 | obtainContent                         in     ''
|    153 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    369 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    109 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     83 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     97 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     78 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    112 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     54 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    187 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|     40 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     79 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter
|    381 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     79 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    381 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    168 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    343 | invokeDelegate                        in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    260 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     69 | doFilterInternal                      in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|    106 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     67 | doFilterInternal                      in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|    106 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     46 | doFilterInternal                      in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|    106 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                      in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     65 | doFilter                              in com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|     88 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
|    106 | doFilter                              in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    343 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    260 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                              in     ''
|    220 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
|    122 | invoke                                in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
|    170 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
|     98 | invoke                                in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
|    950 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve
|    116 | invoke                                in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
|    408 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
|   1040 | process                               in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
|    607 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
|   1721 | doRun                                 in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor
|   1679 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   1145 | runWorker                             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                                   in java.lang.Thread
```

**What does this error mean and how can I prevent it?**

Comment: Hi confile. I don't know if it is solved now, but I just had the same error. On my project, it was because I forgot to add the property generator:assigned in the mapping of my domain (String id generated with RandomStringUtils)

Comment: @Abincepto Could you please provide some sample code for your answer an explain what you mean in more details?